# Will cookie created by js be sent to server when user refresh the page? How to stop that?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I would like to create a local data and when user access the same page, the local data is retrieved.

There is absolutely no need to send the data to the server.

Will cookie be able to achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: localStorage is HTML5 concept. Some browsers doesn't support it, say IE6, I guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cookie will be sent to the server with every request. If you don't *mind* that, then cookies are fine. If you'd rather *avoid* that, you'll need to look into [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage).

Comment: Ok, thanks, I found a nice plugin JStorage. I'll have a look at it.